# Image resizing to 100% in responsive design

Tags: css, image, responsive-design

I have a WordPress site with a Child Theme of Twenty Twelve. It has an image for the Red Lion Hotel towards the bottom of this page: http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/partner-hotels/

It is automatically sizing to fill 100% of the table that it is in. I tried adding it outside of the table and it does the same thing. If I change the image it does the same.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.redlion.com/our-hotels/california/rancho-cordova/">
<img class="size-full wp-image-423 alignleft" width="150" height="169" src="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/redlion.jpg" alt="Red Lion Hotel" title="Red Lion Hotel">
</a>
```

And the applicable CSS:

```
img {
    border: 0 none;
    max-width: 540px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I know that I have it set to width: 100% but that is so when the site resizes for smaller devices, larger images will stay within the screen.

Any tips will be appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: Remove 100% and put it in a media query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it from width to max-width:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

That should do the trick.